# gridview height changes based on image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gridview, xamarin.android

i am trying to create a gridview, where image size is always different. I want grid col height to be same and image to shrink and fit inside grid

below is a image of what i want:

[image]

below is my grid code

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="67*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
             <Image x:Name="ImageURLFront" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Aspect="Fill"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                <Image x:Name="ImageURLBack" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
       </Grid>
```

**issue: w**hat i can tell is that, right image is expanding vertically full screen bc its a long picture

**code out put** grid height chances based on image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

worked for me

```
 <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="ImageURLFront" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"></Image>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ImageURLBack" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"></Image>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Green"></StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Blue"></StackLayout>
            </Grid>
```